# Unlock the page on specific query string

Tags: php

I want to add a query string that "unlocks" the page. here's what i mean:

if a user just types like **some_url.com/index.php** then the user would be surfaced different content in the body of that page that says "Please login to site"

And if only when a user types in **some_url.com/index.php?id=12221983** then the actual content that is developed for that page should be show up

I am little new to this and just know that for such query string `$_GET[""]` can be used. But don't know how should I do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ Epodax: Can you please then suggest another way to achieve that other than `$GET`?

Comment: Create a login system with username / password and store it in a database and then have the users login.

Comment: have tried to use sessions?

Comment: There are a lot of ways. But it seems that you are developing in a live system, that is a big mistake... Take a development area, put an password on it ( http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/ ) and take any change of destroying something on an live website.

Comment: @ Terabyte: not tried that as now there is no need to develop database login system. Its a initial stage so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($_GET['id'] == 12221983) {
    // show good stuff
} else {
    // show bad stuff
}
```

A better option to keep things separate would be to redirect the user if that didn't match.

```
if ($_GET['id'] != 12221983) {
    header('Location: notauthpage.php');
    exit;
}

// just your normal authorised stuff here
```

Then create a new page `notauthpage.php` that has the alternative content.

By looking at the proposed URL being at the root of the domain, it appears that you are trying to lock casual visitors out of something. A better option might be to use a `.htpasswd` and `.htaccess` combination to enable basic authentication. This isn't a comprehensive security option, but it does remove the need to PHP code for this scenario. Most web hosts will even have a section of their control panel available for exactly such a thing. Even without the control panel, setting up basic authentication with Apache is really simple and you'll find loads of good tutorials by googling "Apache basic auth".

Comment: Can we use `div` to the good stuff and bad stuff and then property `display:block` for good stuff and `display:none` for bad stuff?

Comment: @kiran it all depends on what the good/bad stuff is. With them both being on the page, it's just a matter of someone opening the developer tools. Is this for show or for security? If it's just for show and just a small chunk, then use CSS/JS, if it's for security, use PHP to keep the content out of the browser.